# VS2010 error : LNK1181 : cannot open input file xxxx.obj (only in debug mode)

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am using visual Studio 2010, trying to build a big solution having many VC++ projects converted from older Visual Studio builds.

The problem is, it gives me this LNK1181 for the 'root' project of the solution (the project on which all other projects are dependent) but only in DEBUG mode (win32). In release mode, it does not give me this error.

I noticed that this obj file is actually not created at all when in debug mode. Though the compiler doesn't give any error when it is building that cpp file.

What could be the problem? Is it related to those property manager sheets too somehow or something else?

The project is downloaded from our Source Control System directly, and works fine on other machines so there is something wrong on mine :(.

Comment: In Property, Linker->Input you should have to include the path of the .obj file like "../../xxx.lib"

Comment: Hi vikky, the obj file is not created at all...and the settings are same in Debug and Release mode ... then why is it created in Release mode only?

Answer (score 0):

Click on solution.
goto Build menu and clean the solution and again build the solution hopefully this action sove your issue

Answer (score 0):

You probably solved this a long time ago, but when I had this exact issue, removing the source files used to create the object from the project and then re-adding them as existing items fixed the issue. Of course, this doesn't change the fact that you're using project/solution files from your repo that other people are using without issue, which is odd.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I had accidentally added *.obj files to the project, and so it was throwing this error.